# Custom shortcusts advice

Tags: shortcut-keys

The problem with my laptop is that it has no FN shortcut for changing the music number. So i wanted to make a custom shortcut for that.

The combination was

ctr+shift+l.

But i after some tests i experience that the combination was already used.  The most shortcuts that i try ed after that where also already used by programs. 
\

Can get some advice about making custom shortcuts?

I want to thank you guys already. For the post that you will make.

Answer (score 1):

Usually shortcuts involving <kbd>Super</kbd> *(i.e. win-logo)* key are mostly unused, and F[1..12] keys with modifiers. And even without a modifier the <kbd>F1</kbd> never does anything useful. Well, usually it calls "help" in different apps — but c'mon, nobody looks in there anyway, peoples are using either `man` command or the Internet. And even if they would — this is the last thing one would want to bind to a hotkey.

So you could use something like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> for **Next**. If it turn out to be used by WM, add one more modifier, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>, that combination is definitely unused.

**UPD**: some more keys:

<kbd>Insert</kbd>: I don't recall anybody using it. Whilst I do admit the usefulness of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> action in VIM-like editors, but this is a very special case *(I can elaborate further, but not sure anybody interested)*, and doesn't involve <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. FWIW I've took <kbd>Insert</kbd> out of my keyboard at home, and bound a noop action on Kubuntu at work *(I couldn't afford to cripple a keyboard I don't own ☺)* because before my touch-type got better I kept accidentally pressing it. But you can bind something useful in there instead. *(nowadays I'm binding <kbd>XF86AudioPlay</kbd> to be produced by <kbd>Insert</kbd>)*

<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>: that key is so unused, that distro-makers are actually using Scroll Lock LED to show a language layout instead. So you can bind something there too.

<kbd>Num pad keys</kbd>: this one depends on your workflow. E.g. I am, as a programmer, have got touch-type good enough to use the numbers of the keyboard part with letters. So I never ever use num pad. And recently that I've got a keyboard without media keys, I seriously am thinking of rebinding num-pad keys through `xdotool` to [media ones](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols).